# Windows authentication mode working on one computer, but not another

Tags: .net, iis, windows-8

We have two development machines, each one running Windows 8, and IIS 8, same versions. I have setup the exact same site, on both machines, but on one machine I get 401.2 error, removing

```
<authentication mode="Windows" /> 
<authorization>   <deny users="?" /> </authorization>
```

from web.config gives me access again, but this is of course not how we want it to run.

I have set IIS exactly the same (Allow all users), and made sure folder permissions are correct, to test i have given everyone full access to the site folder.

I have tried in IE, Chrome and FireFox.

Question is, what have i overlooked?

Comment: Does anything change if you set it to NTLM?

Comment: First machine, everything is still working, second machine gets a prompt for username and password, type in correct username and password and it fails, gets asked to input again.

Comment: Fixed! He didnt not have HTTP Activation for WCF Services enabled in windows features. Enabling this seemed to fix it, dont really know why, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding HTTP Activation under WCF services in windows features. As well as WCF http activation and non http activation under .net 3.5.

Anyone knows why this had to be enabled, feel free to ellaborate!